# How can I send whatsapp message to multiple numbers by using ultramsg and PHP

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

I am trying to send WhatsApp message to multiple numbers by using [Ultramsg.com](http://Ultramsg.com) using PHP

by reference: https://docs.ultramsg.com/api/post/messages/chat

the code is like this:

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.ultramsg.com/instance1xxx/messages/chat",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "token=exxxxxxxx&to=1408XXXXXX1 @c.us,1408XXXXXX2 @c.us&body=WhatsApp API on UltraMsg.com works good&priority=10",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

but I am getting this error

> "to": "Wrong 'to' format for element (1408xxxxxxx @c.us,1408xxxxxxx @c.us). 'to' format : 14155552671@c.us or 14155552671-441234567890@g.us"

I am not understanding this.

Comment: the error looks quite clear to me; your `to` value is the wrong format. Adjust and retry.

Comment: @Martin that's what the question is about ...

Answer (score 0):

I think should try to remove space before @c.us